# Photon Unity 3D SDK crashes when exporting to WebGL

Tags: unity-game-engine, multiplayer, photon, unity-webgl

In Unity 5.3 the Photon-Unity3D-SDK 4.0.0.12 crashes with error **CS0246** 
it cannot find type or namespace name **SocketWebTcp**.

Do I have to try an older version of Unity or wait for a new version of Photon SDK?

Comment: Looks like your current Unity player set to WebGL. Photon Unity3D SDK does not support this player currently. Try another platform.

Comment: @photonians Thanks for the prompt response. I have to wait for a new version of SDK then!

Comment: @photonians. Do you have any update on this. Did you consider a different game server perhaps which works with Unity WebGL?

Comment: Unity 3D SDK v4.0.5.1 with WebGL support published today.

Answer (score 0):

The same error still occurs.

I just comment out the 129 line in the script "Chat Client"
Also, I removed the build option "Run in background" and "Strip engine code" to prevent сrush of the WebGL build in a browser later. It works for me.

Unity version: 5.3.1f1

Photon Unity Network version: 1.66